# What is a good 3D scatter plot tool?

Tags: raw-data

I am currently doing an Astronomy internship at an institute and one of my tasks includes preparing a 3D scatterplot tool for the Chirp mass, effective spin and the redshift for binary mergers (NS-NS, NS-BH, BH-BH), and I am not sure which tool to use. I found a few resources online, out of which, the most useful source I could find gave the following plot:
[image]
But I feel the image is not too clear and is not too useful (I still haven't labelled the axes). The actual graph is dynamic and can be rotated, zoomed-in/out, etc. but the 3D space on which the graph is being plotted seems to be quite restricted. I was wondering if there are any  better resources to prepare the scatterplot? I was using python initially; however, at least the method that I am using produced a static model.

Comment: So you are not asking for means to produce a 3D scatter plot (like the title suggests), but rather for a tool which gives you a dynamic or interactive 3D scatter plot which you can manipulate live?

Comment: with matplotlib / python: https://rukshanpramoditha.medium.com/creating-interactive-3d-plots-in-matplotlib-7200e7514fec (search for "matplotlib 3d scatter plot dynamic" and you get zillions of entries)

Comment: Gnuplot can do this http://www.gnuplot.info/

Comment: Different but related in Academia SE [Scientific paper with 3D scatterplot in supplementary information; I can add a video but how to let readers rotate/zoom interactively?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/184841/69206)

Comment: I think Python's Matplotlib has a feature that scales the color or saturation with "distance" from viewer. It's not perfect but it's better than nothing. From https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html#scatter-plots see `depthshade=True ` and [this answer to *3D pyplot scatter opacity by depth*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62402507/3904031) You can also set the colors and sizes of the individual markers from any calculated array you supply.